# When would we favor the use of overloading rather than function templates

Tags: c++

In what scenario would you favor the usage of function overloading over using a function template in C++?

Comment: A function template can be too broad. Example: `template<class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)` can wreak utter havoc.

Answer (score 1):

You would favour overloading when there is no generalised version of the function that makes sense, as the class is not designed to be used with arbitrary types. In non-library development, this is the common case.

Probably the most fundamental reasons is that, without some template meta-programming, polymorphism will not work with function templates. Consider the case where you have specialised a function to be passed a Base reference, the non-specialised template function will be a better match for Derived object parameters, rather than your specialisation.

As stated, you can get around it with template meta-programming, but then you start to write the rules that are baked into the language for overloading, at which point you are making you code more complicated than it needs to be.